# xterm key translations

Tags: xorg, xterm, key-binding, translation, resources

The following lines for `~/.Xresources` work only partially in `xterm`:

```
xterm*VT100.Translations:       #override   \n\
        Shift <Key> BackSpace:  string("2") \n\
  Alt   Shift <Key> BackSpace:  string("4") \n\
  Ctrl  Shift <Key> BackSpace:  string("6")
```

What happens is that <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>
is correctly translated but the other two turn out to be the same.

**Is it possible to translate those three key combinations
to different strings?**

Answer (score 2):

```
xterm*VT100.Translations: #override \n\
  ~Alt ~Ctrl Shift<Key>BackSpace: string("2") \n\
  Alt Shift<Key>BackSpace: string("4") \n\
  Ctrl Shift<Key>BackSpace: string("6")
```

`~Alt` means "Alt is not pressed".